# 28P01--Password authentication failed for user in DataGrip

Tags: sql, postgresql, authentication, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I am using `DataGrip` to practice databases (`PostgresSQL`) and I ended up with this error when trying to execute my query (it basically doesn't accept the user/pass I create even when I try it in the test connection). Can someone guide me how to set it correctly?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My assumption was that the username/pass would be created by this GUI but it expects you to have a user/pass already created:

```
 ~   master ⭑  psql -U postgres                           ➶ 2  09:50:56 PM 
psql (9.3.2)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \du
                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}

postgres=# CREATE USER mona WITH PASSWORD 'MYPASSWD';
CREATE ROLE
```

And then I entered the information and was able to execute my query.