# JDBC, Docker, PostgreSQL I can't connect to the database, the password is incorrect. SQLState 28p01

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, jdbc

I'm trying to use the database, but I can't connect to it, I haven't found any solutions on the Internet, so please tell me what the problem is.

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "monitorService"
      POSTGRES_USER: "username"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "12345"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./src/main/resources/volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

MigrationUtil

```
package org.monitoringservice.util;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class MigrationUtil {

    public static void migrateDB(){
        Properties properties = PropertiesUtil.getApplicationProperties();
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                properties.getProperty("url"),
                properties.getProperty("username"),
                properties.getProperty("password")))
        {
            System.out.println(connection.getSchema());
        }catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

PropertiesUtil

```
package org.monitoringservice.util;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class PropertiesUtil {
    public static Properties getApplicationProperties(){
        Properties p = new Properties();
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        try {
            p.load(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("application.properties"));
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return p;
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/monitorService
username=username
password=12345
changeLogFile=liquibase/changelog.xml
defaultSchemaName=monitoring
```

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1Qeh.png)

I tried to recreate the database, change the port. I tried to switch the database encoding, but without success.

Comment: shouldn't you be using your container's ip address instead of localhost?

Comment: @Abhinav How can I get it?

Comment: Using localhost is correct as his port is binded to his container port. After a quick search on your SQLState 28P01: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35966161/28p01-password-authentication-failed-for-user-in-datagrip. There's other question on this error but it means that's you have a authentification error.   
Also, be aware that you should not post screen of error message but copy/paste them instead.

Comment: @Skunka I found out what one of the mistakes was, but it didn't help completely.I have turned off the postgresql service in Windows. Now the errors are more specific. Here's what docker gives out: 
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "user"
DETAIL:  Role "user" does not exist.
Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"

Comment: @Skunka Thanks for the help. I found the answer and wrote it

Comment: @swatter, good to hear ! Don't forget to mark you answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was two things.

**First**, if you had *PostgreSQL installed, then stop its service*, in my case, it was called

> postgresql-x64-16 - PostgreSQL Server 16

After that, the errors began to be displayed correctly, and not in strange characters, as in the picture in the question. And also logs began to arrive in the docker container.

**Secondly**, I used *docker-compose.yml* and indicated where my volumes are located:

> ./src/main/resources/volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data

And in the logs of the database container I had:

> PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping
> initialization

*If you have the same log, then you need to delete volumes*. I just deleted the contents of the volume folder in my project and then restarted docker.compose. [You can also delete volume via commands](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/773).